# BS 5 - Hamburger stuck collapsed when inspect in devtools it stays in collapse show, wont close on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

As stated in the title, when I click on the navbar button the navbar won't collapse but stays open.

Earlier I had the data-toggle problem where you have to have data-bs-toggle in bootstrap 5. And I fixed that.

But this problem I can't find any answer too.

When I inspect the `<div class ="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">` in devTools it changes to
`<div class ="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbar">` upon click.
When I click the button to collapse the navbar it says collapsing but wont go back to collapse but stays as collapse show.

[image: Here's my code.]

Comment: Instead of the an image, please put the code in the relevant question itself. Also there's no reason to use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and `pooper.js` + `bootstrap.min.js`.. This can cause conflicts. Simply use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and `pooper.js` + `bootstrap.min.js`. This can cause conflicts. Simply use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`.